# How to create a square wave with random cycle?

Tags: matlab, signals, wave

I am trying to create a square wave with random cycle (like binary code). How can I draw it like this picture?

[image: square wave]

I tried `rand` function but when there is just 1 one between zeros, then the graph is not similar to the square wave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`randi`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) function to generate the random binary sequence and the [`stairs`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stairs.html) function to visualize the sequence.

The following example generates a random sequence of 10 binary digits and generates a plot of the sequence.

```
x = randi([0 1], 1, 10);
stairs([x, x(end)]);
axis equal;
```

This is the result:

[image: Random binary sequence]